# Serializing Non-form Elements

Tags: jquery, each

I am trying to serialize data that are contained within a series of divs.

After a bit of research I am using the function;

```
function save_values() {

var data = new Array();

$('.category-name').each(function() {
    data.push({ 'name':$(this).attr("name"), 'value':$(this).attr("id")});
});

alert(data);

};
```

My divs are set up like this;

```
<div class = "category">
<div class = "category-number">
    <span>1.0</span>
<div class = "category-name">
    <span>Content</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "category">
<div class = "category-number">
    <span>2.0</span>
<div class = "category-name">
    <span>Content2</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm after a way to efficiently capture content in the category-name divs, as well as content in the category-number divs. I'd prefer to preserve the order of each category-div and the data contained within. Therefore, calling the .each function again for '.category-number' would not be preferable.

Can anyone suggest a way to capture all data within the category-number and category-name divs, in order?

The alert is there for testing only, though is there a better way of displaying the values within the array?

Thanks.

Comment: there are no id/name attribute for the `category-name` elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no `id` or name attributes for the `category-name` elements, from what I can understand you are trying to get the values from `category-number` and `category-name` elements.

try

```
function save_values() {
    var data = $('.category').map(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            $cn = $(this).find('.category-number');
        return {
            'name': $.trim($cn.children('span').text()),
            'value': $.trim($cn.find('.category-name span').text())
        };
    }).get();
    console.log(data);    
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Zg54s/)

Comment: You need to switch the value/name round in your fiddle but other than that it looks good. Thanks for introducing me to .map()

Comment: Thank you, this works quite nicely, and I can tailor the function to the problem.